# How to speed up the io/parsing of a text file containing graph data

Tags: c++, parsing, io, ifstream

so I have this assignment where I am to implement the A* algorithm, but my reading of the graph node data from a file is incredibly slow, taking about 4 min, I wonder if there is a way to speed this up significantly.

(the kart object is just a node vector, the focus of this question is the io)

```
ifstream ifs_edge("<my path>", ios::binary | ios::ate);
    auto edges_size = ifs_edge.tellg();
    ifs_edge.seekg(ios::beg);
    string str_edges(edges_size, 0);
    ifs_edge.read(&str_edges[0], edges_size);
    cout << edges_size << endl;

    int counter = 0;
    double lon = 0, lat = 0;
    string substr;
    for (char c : str_edges)
    {
            if (c != 0x20 && c != 0x0A)
                    substr += c;
            else
            {
                    if (substr.size())
                    {
                            if (counter == 1)
                                    lon = stod(substr);
                            if (counter == 2)
                                    lat = stod(substr);
                            substr.clear();
                            counter++;
                    }
            }
            if (c == 0x0A)
            {
                    counter = 0;
                    if (lon && lat)
                    {
                            astar::kart_node kn;
                            kn.c = { lon, lat };
                            kart.push_back(kn);
                    }
            }
    }
```

EDIT: the file in questions is structured like this:
first line = number of nodes, following are [index] [longitude] [latitude]

```
    3901630
0 55.6345147 12.0729268
1 55.6345880 12.0722614
2 55.6346358 12.0705787
3 55.6390838 12.0686184
```

EDIT 2:
Faster solutions have been supplied, which is great, but for some strange reason it's waay slower for me, I have tried several computers as well. The mystery remains and I'm open to more suggestions, and the question is not to be marked as solved yet, even though my solution has been improved.

Comment: Can you show what the file looks like?

Comment: Of course, I added it now.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a lot of string manipulation and single conversions in your code.  All of that can be avoided and the longitude and latitude can be read directly into floating point variables.  In this case it looks like the entire thing can be reduced to

```
ifstream ifs_edge("<my path>");
int eater; // used to eat the first line and the index of each lon,lat pair
double lon, lat;
std::size_t size;
ifs_edge >> size; //get size for vector
std::vector<astar::kart_node> kart;
kart.reserve(size);
while(ifs_edge >> eater >> lon >> lat)
    kart.emplace_back(lon, lat);
```

Now we have space reserved for the vector to avoid repeated memory allocations and copies; there is no more string conversions; and each `kart_node` is constructed in the vector instead of constructed and then copied.

Comment: Hint. If only one line of the data is maleformed, this would break the whole reading process! 
You should make it more robust to prevent attacks and so!

Comment: I get an exception, std::length_error, I also noticed that the file actually has some excessive spacing between the doubles and indices, should that matter?

Comment: @Jontahan spacing should not matter as `>>` ignores white space.

Comment: @ThomasRoskop Input validation is left to the OP.  It is omitted here for generality and brevity.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's fine!

Comment: For some reason this code reads the size as -858993460 and it reads no more than that, I tried restarting to reset the file privileges, but it didn't help, what's wrong now? (Sorry for spawning two new problems when you're solving one btw)

Comment: @Jontahan You need to make sure the first line of the file is a number.  I also made a change to the code to make `size` a `size_t` instead of a `int`.  You also need to make sure the file is actually open.

Comment: So I got to run it now, it used 197.98s to do the whole file, is this an expected runtime?

Comment: @Jontahan I do not think so.  I was able to read a file formatted like yours in debug build in 35 seconds.  It had 3901630 records in it.

Comment: Hmm, weird, I literally copied your code, and my processor is not at all bad. Any idea as to why it's so slow? I have tried so many techniques.

Comment: @Jontahan Not sure.  [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86aad8ddd80bcf49) is the exact code I ran.

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is standardlized, you can use fstream or fscanf.

Here's the output:
fstream takes about 7.2s
fscanf takes about 1.6s

```
Reading from data.txt
1000000 entry read!
2000000 entry read!
3000000 entry read!
last entry: -116.239,89.5744
read_file_cpp 7.19992s
1000000 entry read!
2000000 entry read!
3000000 entry read!
last entry: -116.239,89.5744
read_file_c 1.55708s
```

Here is the code, compiled with clang++ -O3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void read_file_cpp(const string& path, vector<pair<double, double> >* kart) {
  ifstream in(path);
  int n, index;
  double lon, lat;
  in >> n;
  for (int i=1;i<=n;++i) {
    in >> index >> lon >> lat;
    kart->push_back(make_pair(lon, lat));
    if(i % 1000000 == 0)
      cout << i << " entry read!" <<endl;
  }

  in.close();
}

void read_file_c(const string& path, vector<pair<double, double> >* kart) {
  FILE* f = fopen(path.c_str(),"r");
  int n, index;
  fscanf (f, "%d", &n);
  double lon, lat;

  for (int i=1;i<=n;++i) {
    fscanf(f, "%d %lf %lf", &index, &lon, &lat);
    kart->push_back(make_pair(lon, lat));
    if(i % 1000000 == 0)
      cout << i << " entry read!" <<endl;
  }

  fclose(f);
}

void generate_data(const string& path, int n) {

  cout << "generating data... " << endl;

  ofstream out(path);
  out << n << endl;
  for (int i=0;i<n;++i) {
    float lon = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX) * 360 - 180;
    float lat = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX) * 360 - 180;
    out << i << " " << lon << " " << lat << endl;
  }
  out.close();

  cout << "done !" << endl;
}


int main() {
  const string path = "data.txt";
  vector<pair<double, double> > data;

  // generate_data(path, 3901630);
  {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    read_file_cpp(path, &data);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "last entry: " << data.back().first << "," << data.back().second << endl;

    cout << "read_file_cpp "<< elapsed_secs << "s" << endl;
  }

  data.clear();

  {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    read_file_c(path, &data);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "last entry: " << data.back().first << "," << data.back().second << endl;

    cout << "read_file_c "<< elapsed_secs << "s" << endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: So your read_file_c is the fastest function I've tried so far, but it still uses 100s.

Comment: read_file_cpp 94.965s, literally the same code, I used your file generator as well.

Comment: In that case, the problem might be your, the IO is no longer the bottleneck.